# Button setOnClickListener onCreateView() or onActivityCreated() in Fragment

Tags: android

[by this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32656807/3838663)
I can't understand where to put my `onClickListener()` - inside `onCreateView()` or inside `onActivityCreated()` , below codes describe it better:

**CODE A:** (Setting Button click listener inside `onActivityCreated()`)

```
  private FloatingActionButton bt;      

  @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
              // do something.
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_frag, container, false);
        bt = (FloatingActionButton) v.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        return v;
    }
```

**CODE B:** (Setting Button click listener inside `onCreateView()`)

```
    private FloatingActionButton bt;      

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_frag, container, false);
        bt = (FloatingActionButton) v.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
              // do something.
            }
        });            
        return v;
    }
```

I may have not understood which code is better because of my poor English, anyway, thank you all :)

Comment: In your **CODE A**, you're still initialising `bt` in `onCreateView()` so, I don't see why you don't want to set click listener there too.

Comment: Both will have no effect as far as I know. Once the view is inflated you can put it anywhere either in onCreateView() or in onActivityCreated().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both will have no effect as far as I know. Once the view is inflated you can put it anywhere either in `onCreateView()` or in `onActivityCreated()`.

After all, for binding views and setting click listeners, `onViewCreated()` is a better candidate though, as it will be called immediately after `onCreateView`. It clearly suggests that your `view` has been inflated.

There is no specific reason or rule for it. Google [itself doesn't](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/feedback/SessionFeedbackFragment.java) care much [about it](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/session/SessionDetailFragment.java). As a rule of thumb, you can put it anywhere you want once the view is inflated.

Comment: Okay, Thanks. also, can you give an example for something I need to call inside onActivityCreated() ?

Comment: @DAVIDBALAS1 Anything with Loader Managers. And if you need anything else from the activity view hierarchy such as Toolbar or FloatingActionButton.

Comment: @DAVIDBALAS1You can ask separate question form that. You will get answer from community. I mean I'm not free right now.

Comment: @KrupalShah Thanks. :)

Comment: The links are broken. :'(

Comment: @Alston Yeah. Better to check https://github.com/google/iosched source.

Comment: UPDATE: onActivityCreated was deprecated in API level 28! Better use onCreateView.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest putting the onClickListener it inside the onActivityCreated. And binding the button to the view inside onCreateView. Just like you have done the first time in your question.

To read more regarding the methods you can go through this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28929637/difference-and-uses-of-oncreate-oncreateview-and-onactivitycreated-in-fra?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Any specific reason to support this?

Answer (score 0):

Since `onActivityCreated` was [deprecated in API level 28](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle)), it's probably wise to put it in `onCreateView`!