# Android(Fragment) - Is it recommended to initialize a view object inside onActivityCreated method?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-oncreateview

`View` variables of fragments can be initialised in `onCreateView`method in this way.Here the `TextView` is inside the fragment.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmant_two,container,false);
    if(savedInstanceState == null)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        String data = savedInstanceState.getString("data");
        TextView myText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        myText.setText(data);
    }


    return view;


}
```

But I found that a view is initialized inside `onActivityCreated`  in this way.

```
textView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.text_view);
```

is there any reason for which I should choose `onActivityCreated` over   `onCreateView` ?

Answer (score 6):

```
textView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.text_view);
```

This will try to find the view with id `R.id.text_view` from the layout of your activity, not your fragment. If the view with that id is present in your fragment itself then you should use the `onCreateView` method within your fragment.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmant_two,container,false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    // bind your data here.
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Obviously onActivityCreated was used because the view is found on the Activity.

You could also use onAttach for that, though.

Personally, onViewCreated is where I put my Fragment view initializations

Comment: I have edited my question . Actually , the view was not from the Activity rather it was from the fragment . So , from your opinion should I initialize the `view` (here , the `textView`) using `onCreateView ` ?

Comment: If it was in the Fragment, then you should not use `getActivity().findViewById`

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to this question to understand more about onActivityCreated and onCreateView [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28929637/difference-and-uses-of-oncreate-oncreateview-and-onactivitycreated-in-fra)

> **onCreate():**
>
> The onCreate() method in a Fragment is called after the Activity's
>   onAttachFragment() but before that Fragment's onCreateView(). In this
>   method, you can assign variables, get Intent extras, and anything else
>   that doesn't involve the View hierarchy (i.e. non-graphical
>   initialisations). This is because this method can be called when the
>   Activity's onCreate() is not finished, and so trying to access the
>   View hierarchy here may result in a crash.
>
> **onCreateView():**
>
> After the onCreate() is called (in the Fragment), the Fragment's
>   onCreateView() is called. You can assign your View variables and do
>   any graphical initialisations. You are expected to return a View from
>   this method, and this is the main UI view, but if your Fragment does
>   not use any layouts or graphics, you can return null (happens by
>   default if you don't override).
>
> **onActivityCreated():**
>
> As the name states, this is called after the Activity's onCreate() has
>   completed. It is called after onCreateView(), and is mainly used for
>   final initialisations (for example, modifying UI elements).

Answer (score 0):

[onCreateView()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle)): You can assign your View variables and do any graphical initialisations here.

[onActivityCreated()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle)): It is called after onCreateView(), and is mainly used for final initialisations (for example, modifying UI elements).

Answer (score 0):

In onCreateView, you may not be able to use getActivity.findViewByID()

But you can in onActivityCreated.

I also suggest using onView Created(). You can use getActivity.findViewByID()
here too.